# How to restrict object creation when certain condition is met

Tags: c++

I have this problem: I wrote a C++ class that represents a remote device with a given address (there can be several devices on a bus, each one with a different address). The address is passed to the class as a constructor's parameter at object creation time. Each instance of the class should have a different address, if you tried to create two objects with the same address, the class should reject it (as a kind of singleton, but with a parameter). How can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Put the used addresses into a static set in the constructor (and remove them in the destructor). Check the map when you construct a new object. Your requirements also imply that you cannot copy or assign these objects. So delete your copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you, your solution sounds similar to the code posted below ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way is to keep track of addresses already used at class level:

```cpp
class Monopoly {
    Address addr;
    static std::unordered_set<Address> taken;
public:
    Monopoly(Address const &a): addr(a) {
        if(!taken.insert(a).second) {
            throw std::logic_error(a.toString() + " is already in use");
        }
    }
    Monopoly(Monopoly &&) = default;
    Monopoly(Monopoly const &) = delete;
    Monopoly &operator=(Monopoly &&) = default;
    Monopoly &operator=(Monopoly const &) = delete;
    ~Monopoly() { taken.erase(addr); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a class with a member variable (address) that's initialized by a value passed as a parameter to the constructor and you don't want the object to be built if another object already has the address you passed.

You could handle that by storing all the objects in a vector, and then use a for loop to compare the passed address with each adress of each already existing object in the vector and throw an exception, or use assert, or create some kind of error if the passed address is equal to an exiting address.

If you don't want to store the objects in a vector, you can create a vector that only holds adresses.

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. Yours is another possible solution, but I prefer to try to solve it within the class. The class utilization will be beyond my control, therefore, I think it is better to have some kind of internal mechanism within it that controls the creation of objects. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There are container types much more efficient for this purpose than vector.